# Codeigniter - upload not working in 000webhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

The codeigniter `do_upload` function would not work in `000webhost`.
I had already set the `uploads` folder permission to `777`.
If I do it in `XAMPP`, it will work but in `000webhost` ftp it wouldn't.
The following section shows my code:

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        redirect('customer/viewCustomer');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        echo "success";
    }

    $upload_file = $this->upload->data();

}
```

Comment: 000Webhost has a file size limit, and that is only upto **2mb** on free servers

Comment: Hello, my file is less than 2mb. It can't be uploaded.